# ssh-add not working for some hosts

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

My ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_rsa
```

I know that this doesn't make any sense since it's the same key but it was like that because at some point I was using a different key as default. With this config I notticed the following behaviour:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/some_rsa
Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/some_rsa: 
Identity added
$ ssh user@host
<connects fine>
$ git clone git@github.com:some/repo.git
Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/some_rsa:
```

Both connections should work with the same key. Can anyone explain this?